# How to access x:name in Views inside ListView x:name? And is it possible to set different forms of user input?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm fairly new to Xamarin and making an app that will have a list of items that i want to have the option to like/set as favourite feature to.

But I have an issue with accessing the image view and button view x Names that are out of context due to the x Name in ListView. What i've tried is to have a foreach loop to get as many images and buttons as there's items in the ListView by seperating the ListView, Button and Image into different grid rows.
Sadly that resulted in the Listview populating normally but only one image and one button shows up.

This is what I've tried:
my Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
         x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    
   <Grid>
    <ListView
        x:Name="CategoryList" 
              SelectionMode="None"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FavCategories}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>

          <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ., Converter{converters:ToUpperConverter}}"></Label>
                    
         </ViewCell>
                
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        
    </ListView>
    <Image x:Name="ImgFav"  
     Grid.Column="2" 
     Source="{Binding IsFav}"></Image>
    
     <Button x:Name="BtnFav" 
      Grid.Column="3" 
      Text="{Binding FavState}" 
      Clicked="BtnFav_Clicked"></Button>
                        
  </Grid>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

My C#:

```
public async Task Load()
    {
            ApiService apiService = new ApiService();      
            Categories.Clear();


        List<FavCategoryModel> favCategories = new List<FavCategoryModel>();
            var categories = await apiService.GetCategories();

            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                Categories.Add(category);
            }
        foreach(var item in Categories)
        {

            favCategories.Add(new FavCategoryModel { Category = item, IsFavourite = false });
        }
        
            CategoryList.ItemsSource = favCategories.Select(c =>c.Category.ToString()).ToList();
        var isFavourite = favCategories.Select(f => f.IsFavourite);
        foreach(var isfav in favCategories)
        {
            if (favCategories.Any(f => f.IsFavourite) == false)
            {
                foreach(var category in categories)
                {
                
                ImgFav.Source = "nonFav.Png";
                BtnFav.Text = "Like";
                }

            }
        }
```

So i know if i get it right i should be able to manipulate the Button and Image if they're inside the ListView and get there row corresponding to the categories populating the list.
like this:

```
 <ListView
    x:Name="CategoryList" 
          SelectionMode="None"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FavCategories}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

      <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ., Converter{converters:ToUpperConverter}}"></Label>
      <Image x:Name="ImgFav"  
 Grid.Column="2" 
 Source="{Binding IsFav}"></Image>

 <Button x:Name="BtnFav" 
  Grid.Column="3" 
  Text="{Binding FavState}" 
  Clicked="BtnFav_Clicked"></Button>
     </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

But results in my x names for button and image don't exist in current context.
Does anyone have any wisdom to lend me on how to conquer this obstacle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't access items within a template by name.  Items in a template are generated dynamically at runtime - you should use data binding to populate them.

Comment: 2nd, you can't assign items in the template to your grid rows/cols because the ListView is contained in the Grid, items within the template will be contained in the ListView.  You can put a Grid inside the ViewCell, and then place the template items within that Grid.

Comment: @Jason Yea sorry forgot to adjust that part, that was what i meant that i tried putting grid in the ViewCell.
I will try with the data bindings again sadly i haven't quite grasped the proper use of it yet my only lead is that, thats the proper way to go.

Comment: You are binding your ListView to a `List<string>`.  Instead bind it to a `List<FavCategoryModel>` and then bind the items in your template to the different properties on that model.

Comment: Check [Bindings and Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#bindings-and-collections) or start from a template project and check the bindings for listing and details.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)**, and you will understand the design more clearly. We will not be recommanded to deal with Control directly when using binding ViewMode. In addition, if using `DataTemplate`, we also will not get Control by `x:Name`.

Don't have to worry about how to get the `x:Name` of the control, just focus on the function you want to implement. And it will use MVVM to achieve the functions you want.

For example, my Xaml code as follow:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            RowHeight="150"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemSelected="MyListView_ItemSelected"
            ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}"
            IsVisible="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Hello World"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Address}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding eMail}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                            
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then I will code as follows to make it show my wants:

```
public PageListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var myItems = new List<Contacts>();
    myItems.Add(new Contacts() {Address="1",eMail="1" });
    myItems.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "2", eMail = "2" });
    myItems.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "3", eMail = "3" });
    myItems.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "4", eMail = "4" });
    myItems.Add(new Contacts() { Address = "5", eMail = "5" });

    this.BindingContext = this;
   
}
```

The `Contacts.cs`：

```
public class Contacts
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

===================================Update==============================

If need a default value, you [define a fallback value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-fallbacks#defining-a-fallback-value).

```
<Label Text="{Binding Address, FallbackValue='Address unknown'}"
       ... />
```

And set `ItemSource` from a rest api, here is [the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-todorest).

```
protected async override void OnAppearing ()
{
    base.OnAppearing ();

    listView.ItemsSource = await App.TodoManager.GetTasksAsync ();
}
```

Comment: Have had a look on MVVM aswell and the Data Binding Documentation provided from microsoft, but sadly no example on different data bindings of Controls in the same ViewCell, the examples that did only showed the Xaml but not the code behind.

I may should've mentioned that the list is populated from a Restful API where i take the data from the Get call and put in corresponding column in the List while also adding some default values at startup for the other columns

Comment: @Gabbelino Okey, you could have a look at [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-todorest/) with calling rest api to display data in ListView. The difference between is the data of `ItemsSource`. If you need a default value, you coudl define a [fallback value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-fallbacks#defining-a-fallback-value).

Comment: @Gabbelino I have updated answer, if the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.